# Woocommerce Update subtotal and product price

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have been trying to change the subtotal and product price after the user has clicked on checkout. I managed to change the total using the hook **`woocommerce_checkout_create_order`** and then **`$order->set_total()`**, but there is no such thing for subtotal and product price. I have also tried doing it with **`woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta`** but with no success.

How do I update the subtotal and product price, which hook do I use?

Comment: Why are you trying to change the price?  Are you adding in an extra tax or charge to the customer?

Comment: I need to change the price when a certain amount of quantity is picked, so for example if it is more than 16 i need to change it to 0.